# License for Android NDK toolchain

Tags: android

Cite from https://source.android.com/license

> The preferred license for AOSP is the Apache Software License, Version 2.0 ("Apache 2.0"), and the majority of the Android software is licensed with Apache 2.0. While the project strives to adhere to the preferred license, there may be exceptions that will be handled on a case-by-case basis. For example, the Linux kernel patches are under the GPLv2 license with system exceptions

Both Apache Software License v2 and GPLv2 license are used for Android platform. However, after installing arm NDK build tool-chain (API version 18) on Ubuntu I found below files in the root directory :

- MODULE_LICENSE_BSD_LIKE (empty file)
- MODULE_LICENSE_MIT (empty file)
- MODULE_LICENSE_GPL (empty file)
- NOTICE (mentioning both  Apache Software License v2 and GPLv2 license)

Question :

1. What are the licenses used in NDK?
2. Is different license used for different NDK component?

Answer (score 1):

There are several open source components with various licenses used by it, but the Android NDK as a whole is not open source. To download and use the NDK you'll have to agree to the [Android Software Development Kit License Agreement](https://developer.android.com/studio/terms).

To actually answer your question, I believe you should find information about which licenses apply for open source used by the NDK here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/ndk/+/master/NOTICE

Knowing exactly what goes where is a lot harder to find out.